# SwiftData Fetch Specific Object With UUID

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am trying to fetch specific book from DB i try a lot of things on net but every time i get more errors. The think i dont understand is why this is so hard ? Just fetch an object with id.

```
@Model
final class Book: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var category: Category?
    var author: Author?
    var printDate: String
    var printLenght: Int
    var language: String
    var currentPage: Int = 0
    var isbn: String?
    
    var isFavorite: Bool = false
    var isBookmark: Bool = false
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Category.books)
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Author.books)
    
    init(name: String, printDate: String, printLenght: Int, language: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.printDate = printDate
        self.printLenght = printLenght
        self.language = language
    }
}
```

This is my model  in swiftUI app i just want to fetch a Book object i created earlier.

Comment: You should update your question with your attempts to fetch the specific record and clearly explain the issues you are having.

Comment: What errors are you getting? You haven't included the issues in your question

Comment: The problem is my attempts are loo long. Like creating extensions protocols and weird facts. And i tried a lot of things. Non of them are not worked. I am just asking is there an easy way to do that. I mean it should be right ? just a fetch an item with id @HangarRash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my problem with UUID String.

{$0.id.contains(read.bookId)}

When I change the UUID to UUID String I can now use it to fetch a specific book. I don't know how safe is that but for now i have no complains.